# How do I test Action Bar's Action Items from Robolectric?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Real quick, is there a way in the current Robolectric to verify the *presence* and *visibility* of an action item on the action bar? (I know this basically writing a unit test for a UI configuration detail, but I'd like to do it if it is simple.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there was no possibility to access ActionBar in earlier versions of Robolectric. Trying to get it from Activity returned null.

Since Robolectirc 2.2 http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2013/10/robolectric-22-released.html you can access ActionBar.